# Difference between different BeginTransaction methods.

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, transactions

What is the difference among the following BeginTransaction methods:

1. SqlConnection.BeginTransaction Method
2. DbConnection.BeginTransaction Method
3. DbConnection.BeginDbTransaction Method

Moreover, how they are different from TransactionScope() method in System.Transaction?

Comment: What does the MSDN documentation on these say?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. `SqlConnection.BeginTransaction` creates a `SqlTransaction`, which is specific to MS SQL Server
2. `DbConnection.BeginTransaction` creates a `DbTransaction`, which is generic, and relies on the underlying connection to create a database-specific transaction. If your `DbConnection` is of type `SqlConnection`, this will be a `SqlTransaction`.
3. `DbConnection.BeginDbTransaction` is a protected method that you override if you're creating your own class that inherits from `DbConnection`.

**EDIT:**

These are all specific to the database connection from which they were created, which is used differently than a TransactionScope, which isn't database-dependent. I believe if you wanted to coordinate transactions between multiple connections, you have to explicitly call `DbConnection.EnlistTransaction(transaction)`. With a TransactionScope, a connection will (depending on the database provider, at least it should) automatically enlist in the TransactionScope if one exists when the connection is opened. In WCF, a TransactionScope can also be passed across service boundaries, and can be used to commit the results of multiple service calls as a single transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you please differentiate these from the TransactionScope()? Is there any relation among them?